# Axiom test cases doesn't run

Tags: apache-axis, axiom

I'm working on an Apache Axiom Project. I've wrote juint test cases. And tried to run it. 
But every time they give this error. (saying that corresponding class has no public constructor TestCase )

```
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Class org.apache.axiom.ts.om.builder.TestGetDocumentElementWithIllFormedDocument has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

       Process finished with exit code 255
```

Then I've tried to run some several test cases that were already in the axoim to see if it's because of the code I've written. 
Same error pops up.

I'll appreciate if some one can help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered the question here: http://markmail.org/message/2sxitsvqajapmhap